Showing that the values of the following expression do not depend on x
In Spivak's Calculus, problem 3(a) of chapter 14 asks a proof that the value of the following expression does not depend on $x$ : $$F(x)=\int_0^x \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt+\int_0^{1/x} \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$$
Differeniating and applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we get $F'(x)=0\ \forall\ x\ne 0$. Using the following  corollary of the Mean Value theorem:

If $f'(x)=0$ for all $x\in I$ for some interval $I$, then $f(x)=c$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$ on $I$

we get that $F(x)=C_1$ on $(-\infty,0)$  and $F(x)=C_2$ on $(0,\infty)$. How do we further deduce that $C_1 =C_2 $?? Any hints would be appreciated.

@AnneBauval: It seems to me that $F(-x)$ actually equals $-F(x)$, and hence the function is actually not constant on $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$.

See also many other posts in this list: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_0%5Ex%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2Bt%5E2%7Ddt%2B%5Cint_0%5E%7B1%2Fx%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2Bt%5E2%7Ddt%24&p=1

The integrand is an even function. Hence we have (by using $t \mapsto -t$) $$F(1) =2 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt =-2 \int_0^{-1} \frac{1}{1+(-t)^2}dt=-F(-1)~.$$
Further note that $F(1)>1/2 >0$. Therfore we have $C_1 = -C_2$ and $C_1 \neq C_2$.

Please do not answer such an FAQ. There are already tons of answers about it on this site. Like this one.
